# I broke my Kali desktop for a user after trying to rename them

Tags: linux, debian, kali-linux, rename

The issue probably comes from the fact that I used pkill to allow me to rename the user. But anyway after logging back in as the user, my desktop had no menu / hotbar. Each time I login the terminal opens by default, but I am unable to move it around or exit it. Any idea as to what I ruined?

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PHfn.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. It ended up being a corrupt Xfce session. All I had to do was `cd ~/.cache/session/ && rm -rf *` and reboot